# Import-CSV and ForEach providing unexpected output

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm new here, and this is my first question. I looked through various related questions, but was not able to find an answer, so I'm hopeful that someone can help.

I have a script to create folders for user accounts, and assign them privileges. I have a .csv file with the names of the folders I want to create. When I run the script, it is not producing the desired results, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Contents of .csv file (each on a separate line):

1001

1002

1003...

There are no headers, just the numbers.

PS Script I'm running:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "E:\Support\usersOnly.csv" -Header @("Name")
 ForEach ($line in $csv) {E:\Support\CreateFolders.ps1 -Path     E:\blah\blahblah\$line -Access mydomain\$line -Permission modify}
```

This calls the folder creation script, which looks like this (I found this, it's not mine):

```
param ([string]$Path, [string]$Access, [string]$Permission = ("Modify"), [switch]$help)

function GetHelp() {

$HelpText = @"

DESCRIPTION:
NAME: CreateFolder.ps1
Create Folders and sets permissions for user.


PARAMETERS: 
-Path           Folder to Create or Modify (Required)
-User           User who should have access (Required)
-Permission     Specify Permission for User, Default set to Modify      (Optional)
-help           Prints the HelpFile (Optional)

SYNTAX:
./CreateFolder.ps1 -Path C:\Folder\NewFolder -Access Domain\UserName -Permission FullControl

Creates the folder C:\Folder\NewFolder if it doesn't exist.
Sets Full Control for Domain\UserName

./CreateFolder.ps1 -Path C:\Folder\NewFolder -Access Domain\UserName

Creates the folder C:\Folder\NewFolder if it doesn't exist.
Sets Modify (Default Value) for Domain\UserName

./CreateFolder.ps1 -help

Displays the help topic for the script

Below Are Available Values for -Permission

"@
 $HelpText

[system.enum]::getnames([System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights])

 }

function CreateFolder ([string]$Path) {

# Check if the folder Exists

if (Test-Path $Path) {
    Write-Host "Folder: $Path Already Exists" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
} else {
    Write-Host "Creating $Path" -Foregroundcolor Green
    New-Item -Path $Path -type directory | Out-Null
}
}

function SetAcl ([string]$Path, [string]$Access, [string]$Permission) {

# Get ACL on FOlder

$GetACL = Get-Acl $Path

# Set up AccessRule

$Allinherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$Allpropagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
$AccessRule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Access, $Permission, $AllInherit, $Allpropagation, "Allow")

# Check if Access Already Exists

if ($GetACL.Access | Where { $_.IdentityReference -eq $Access}) {

    Write-Host "Modifying Permissions For: $Access" -ForeGroundColor Yellow

    $AccessModification = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.AccessControlModification
    $AccessModification.value__ = 2
    $Modification = $False
    $GetACL.ModifyAccessRule($AccessModification, $AccessRule, [ref]$Modification) | Out-Null
} else {

    Write-Host "Adding Permission: $Permission For: $Access"

    $GetACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
}

Set-Acl -aclobject $GetACL -Path $Path

Write-Host "Permission: $Permission Set For: $Access" -ForeGroundColor Green
}

if ($help) { GetHelp }

if ($Path -AND $Access -AND $Permission) { 
CreateFolder $Path 
SetAcl $Path $Access $Permission
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Permission: modify Set For: mydomain\@{Name=1018}
Creating E:\blah\blahblah\@{Name=1019}
Adding Permission: modify For: mydomain\@{Name=1019}
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At E:\Support\CreateFolders.ps1:90 char:3
+         $GetACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

Permission: modify Set For: mydomain\@{Name=1019}
Creating E:\blah\blahblah\@{Name=102}
Adding Permission: modify For: mydomain\@{Name=102}
```

It creates a folder with the name '@{Name=102}', when all I want is '102'.

I've also tried this without the header, by adding a line at the top of my .csv file called 'Name', but had no success there either. If I don't include a header, it tries to use the first folder name as the header.

If I run this script manually (without feeding it the .csv), it runs successfully, but I have over a thousand folders to create, so I'd rather automate. I'm sure this is something simple, as I'm new to PS scripting.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: First thing I see wrong is around the line `$csv = Import-Csv "E:\Support\usersOnly.csv" -Header @("Name")`. You have an object array with a `name` property. Consider trying this at the beginnign. `$csv = Import-Csv "E:\Support\usersOnly.csv" -Header @("Name") | Select-Object -Expand Name`. After reading more of your post I see that as being the issue. Answer is forth coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a CSV with no header and one column that you are importing. Currently the way you are importing it is populating `$csv` with and object array with the property name. The rest of your script is treating that as just a string array and ignoring the property. A minor change that would address this problem is to expand that column.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "E:\Support\usersOnly.csv" -Header @("Name") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

But really since it is only one column and no header don't even bother with the CSV aspect of this (it really isn't a CSV anyway.)

```
$csv = Get-Content "E:\Support\usersOnly.csv"
```

Aside from the potential misleading variable name you should just have to change that one line for this to be correct. (Assuming there are not other problems.)

The `@{Name=1018}` you are seeing is the string representation (shown as a hashtable) of one of the elements in *your* `$csv` array.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much, it's greatly appreciated.